# How am I supposed to know where to find the triforce shards in Zelda Wind Waker HD?

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

Without having to refer to walkthroughs, how was I supposed to know where to find all the triforce shards? On my adventures I had uncovered three triforce maps, but what of the rest of the shards? Is it expected that I visit every square on the map in order to locate them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon completion of the Forsaken Fortress, check the mail. Tingle should have sent you the IN-credible Chart, which displays the locations and collection status of all the Triforce Charts and Shards. This will however cost you 201 Rupees.